# How can I export the developer story/CV as Markdown?

Tags: support, markdown, developer-story, cv-export

There used to be an option to export the CV as Markdown (MD):

- User's page - Edit CV - Settings - Create MD

I cannot find that link any longer - how can I get the MD export?

Comment: This is not currently possible with Developer Story but we're looking at improvements to the export feature. I'll update you about the priority of it shortly.

Comment: @Kit Any news on this topic? Any other possibility to export the "raw" text data?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to export a JSON copy of your Developer Story (CV) using the third-party tool https://developerstory.dev/stackoverflow.

The export includes Markdown formatted descriptions for each of the items in your timeline which you could then copy to use elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to **export your developer story** as `.json` using the [MAC](https://github.com/getmanfred/mac) format and docker **in less than 5 minutes**.

Use this command:

```
docker build -t getmanfred/dev-story-scraper https://github.com/getmanfred/dev-story-scraper.git#main && \
docker run -p3000:3000 -d getmanfred/dev-story-scraper && \
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/?username=<profile_user_name' -X GET > MAC.json && \
more MAC.json
```

It works like a charm and is based on the opensource parser version used by [Manfred](https://www.getmanfred.com/stackoverflowgeddon), but you don't have to use their front-end, so your user and data will remain unknown.

[image: Screenshot of Manfred web where you can download your developer story]

**Note**: *you should turn your profile public for the export to work.*

MAC `.json` format is also a community based open source format for CV. And it is possible to import them directly in the creators website, and I hope in many others sites in the future. Information in MAC format will always remain in your control, and synchronized with github repository if you want.

You can read additional information in [this blog post](https://dev.to/dbonillaf/how-to-survive-the-stackoverflowgeddon-7o2)